# What should we do with the new Community Bulletin?

Tags: discussion

So we now have a new [Community Bulletin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130892/1438), which currently lists any [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)  and "[hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/1438)" meta-posts.  However, if we wanted to, we could ask our moderators to set up "events" to publicize.  For instance, we could revive the weekly [challenges](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/challenge).  With the extra visibility, maybe we'd get more participation.

Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: +1 for using this for weekly challenges.